# rabbitmq adds extra character to the message body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, queue

We publish message to the queue and try to read it. Sometimes when try to deserialize object for entity we get some exceptions.

We have seen some extra character on message body and we get the below exception when trying to deserialize body as json.

1- Exception message 1: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path '***', line 1, position 1197.

2 -  Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: e. Path '', line 1, position 863.

after getting error we are logging the message body before deserialization process.

We seen these extra character on log.

**This log message**

Error on Consumer_Notification_Received event! Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: *. Path '', line 0, position 0. Body:

*2
$4
AUTH
$18
insCGTICPassR3d50!
*3
$6
CLIENT
$7
SETNAME
$8
GW-WEB01
*3
$6
databases
*2
$8
SENTINEL
$7
MASTERS
*1
$4
INFO
*2
$7
CLUSTER
$5
NODES
*2
$4
ECHO
$16
����6�G��aV�\B
d":"CtUAAB+LCAAAAAAABADtXe+O2ji7//5K5x6iHumVjlYNCST8mbfLyhAD2fxtEmiZL4idYbecMjACptvZG9g72E+rXsPcw0zv69gJCWGIYzAeSvcgddTYj/3ws/38Hj92nOTN4gJOP40ms9uR8PlmMl1cLH589WG5vL0oFBZXH0Y3w4WI8hez4a04m/9WwBeF0apG4VX9zeKiMbu+r79pj5bubDK+ugd3yw+j6XJ8NVyOZ1NjdO+NFrez6WKlP9G+HN3c3s3HodZXlPp3k+UK3XAL3fVwObyaTZfz4dUyVFaUJKUgVQoQKVne+7fDq9FChJ+Xo/l0OBGjHxG90fJuPh1Pfwvub0evVsrHifLff/9d/L0Uq5ML7y3TD3/v9Xi6WA6nVyMEeXgBrhDSoT2rq2pFKkpvCqksLJ6M5kt0GQlWiTg/GH1eCuOL6Xjy46vl/G70qhCKUOtn8/EfYeMXYVZjuJgMb4bBcD7+UC9KxeJrW

**Here, we publish the message to the queue**

```
var message = JsonConvert.Serialize<T>(object);
var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

var properties = Channel.CreateBasicProperties();
properties.Persistent = isPersistent;

if (headers != null)
  properties.Headers = headers;

Channel.BasicPublish(
   exchange: exchange,
   routingKey: routingKey,
   basicProperties: properties,
   body: body);
```

**Here, we try to read the message from queue**

```
var body = e.Body.ToArray();
message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
var requestModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message);

action.Invoke(requestModel);

// notifies RabbitMq that the notification is complete.
((EventingBasicConsumer)sender).Model.BasicAck(deliveryTag: e.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
```

Not: we log request and response of service requests as compressed strings.

Comment: RabbitMQ **DOES NOT** alter the contents of messages. You have a bug in your application. Unfortunately you have not provided enough code to be able to diagnose the issue. Provide a _complete_ set of code via a git repository (GitHub,GitLab) and follow-up on the mailing list - https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users

Comment: this is almost all the code. Throws exception on line 'JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message)'.

I just serialize my model and convert it to bytes. My consumer is doing the opposite

Comment: Without a way to reproduce there is basically no way we can assist. We know that this is not a bug in RabbitMQ but otherwise I can't even guess where the issue is in your code. If you provide a concrete example, I'm pretty sure I could figure out the issue if you provide data that appears to be modified by RabbitMQ. Please see my earlier comment about the best way to help us help you.